# Regular Expression for double and integer validation

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the following regex:

```
^([1-9][0-9]?)(\.[0-9])?$
```

to validate the following:

```
1     <-- MATCHES
1.5   <-- MATCHES
10    <-- MATCHES
10.5  <-- MATCHES
102   <-- DOES NOT MATCH, BUT SHOULD
```

and not validate the following:

```
0       <-- DOES NOT MATCH, AND SHOULDN'T
0.      <-- DOES NOT MATCH, AND SHOULDN'T
0.5     <-- DOES NOT MATCH, AND SHOULDN'T
0.55    <-- DOES NOT MATCH, AND SHOULDN'T
102.    <-- DOES NOT MATCH, AND SHOULDN'T
102.5   <-- DOES NOT MATCH, AND SHOULDN'T
102.55  <-- DOES NOT MATCH, AND SHOULDN'T
```

The closest I have gotten is the above Regex which currently does everything except match 102. I will apologize ahead of time, I do not know much about Regular Expression.

I had considered using a negative and positive lookup starting at the decimal point if it existed. There should be a max of 2 digits before the decimal and 1 digit after the decimal. If there is no decimal then test for an integer with a max of three positions.

Further explanation:

The script I'm working on is using the regex to validate input using `QRegExpValidator` instead of `QDoubleValidator` or `QIntValidator` because both of those accept `+/-` as a potential entry, and that has been causing some issues.

One of my `QLineEdit` boxes can take either a double or an integer. Entries need to be one to three digits long, and have no decimal, or they need to be one to two digits without starting with a 0, a decimal, and one digit.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to match. Why isn't 0 a match? Why aren't 0.5 and 0.55 matches? Why isn't 102 a match?

Comment: This may work: `^[1-9](?:\d?(?:\.\d)?|\d{2})$`

Comment: You need to explain **why** some of these should match and not others. Right now any answer provided is just pure guess work.

Comment: @pault the no match means my current regex does not match that number.

Comment: Two down votes and no explanation other than comprehension issues, please explain and I will update the question to clarify. It would at least be nice to have a chance to make things right.

Comment: The question is fine now. It was unclear what you meant when you first asked it so you've probably got lingering downvotes

Comment: @pault Updated to clarify.

Comment: Further updated to include one to three digits without a decimal. My original explanation contradicted my examples.

Comment: *or they need to be two digits, decimal, and one digit* But why do you then accept `1.5`??? it doe not follow this logic

Comment: @Onyambu thanks for catching that, I updated the questions to include that in the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) that matches either 3 digits `[1-9][0-9]{2}` or match the regex you tried with the optional part that matches the dot and a single digit.

`^(?:[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9])?)$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FINYIH/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[1-9][0-9]{2}` Match a digit 1-9 followed by 2 digits 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9][0-9]?` Match a digit 1-9 followed by an optional digit
  - `(?:\.[0-9])?` Optional non capturing group that matches a dot and a digit 0-9
- `)` close non capturing group
- `$` Assert the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said:

> Entries either need to be three digits long, greater than 100 and have no decimal, or they need to be two digits, decimal, and one digit.

You can try the following pattern:

```
(^[1-9]\d{1,2}$)|(^[1-9]$)|(^[1-9]\d?\.[1-9]$)
```

The `|` is a logical `OR`, so this is essentially checking for three separate patterns:

1. `(^[1-9]\d{1,2}$)`: Any sequence of 2 or 3 digits, except those starting with `0`
2. `(^[1-9]$)`: Any one digit except `0`
3. `(^[1-9]\d?\.[1-9]$)`: Any sequence of 1 or 2 digits (as long as the first one isn't a `0`) followed by a `.` and exactly one digit that is not `0`

Each of these is wrapped by `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string).

---

If you didn't need to use regex, you could do something like:

```
def match(s):
    if any(not c.isdigit() and c != "." for c in s):
        return False
    if "." not in s:
        return 0 < int(s) < 1000
    elif s.count(".") == 1:
        before, after = s.split(".")
        before_good = (len(before) <= 2 and int(before) != 0)
        after_good = (len(after) == 1 and int(after) != 0) 
        return before_good and after_good
    else:
        return False
```

Testing with your values:

```
validate = {
    "match": ["1", "1.5", "10", "10.5", "102"],
    "nomatch": ["0", "0.", "0.5", "0.55", "102.", "102.5", "102.55", "foo"]
}
matches = all(match(s) for s in validate["match"])
nomatches = any(match(s) for s in validate["nomatch"])
print( matches and not(nomatches))
#True
```

Comment: This was a consideration initially, but I'm using `QRegExpValidator` to ensure that no signal is sent if the input is invalid using the  `EditingFinished` signal. I'm also using the `textEdited` signal to change the color of the text box if the input is invalid.

Comment: @AaronTomason added a regex version

Answer (score -1):

This pattern should do the trick: `^[1-9]\d?(?!\.$)\.?\d?$`

[You can see it here...](https://regex101.com/r/W3LivE/4/)

Here's the breakdown:

- `^[1-9]` means it has to start with a number in that range
- `\d?` is an optional number 0-9
- `(?!\.$)` means it won't match if it is followed by `.` and the end of the line. This prevents results like this from matching: `99.`
- `\.?` matches an optional `.`
- `\d?$` is another optional number 0-9 followed by the end of the match

In this case since the `.` is optional and there is a maximum of 3 digits it will take care of both of your use cases without having to use an or `|`